# Parse Query Not doing anything once inside

Tags: android, parse-platform

My problem is that I am using Parse, but when I try to use the done method once it is in the method, it does nothing. The code gets into the method and then doesn't go into the for loop.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//Useless Stuff

        ParseQuery<settings> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(settings.class);
        query.orderByDescending("CreatedDate").setLimit(1);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<settings>() {
            public void done(List<settings> settingsList, ParseException e) {
                for (settings i : settingsList) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Log.e("Pay Attention", "There is an object");
                        setVisibleInvisible();
                        settingsHiveNumber = i.getHiveNumber();
                        settingsFrameNumber = i.getFramesPerHive();
                        settingsHiveBodyNumber = i.getHiveBodies();
                        settingsSuperNumber = i.getSupers();
                        settingsYearsOfBeekeeping = i.getYearsofBeekeeping();
                        settingsLocation = i.getLocation();
                        setLablesTo(settingsLocation, settingsHiveNumber, settingsFrameNumber, settingsHiveBodyNumber, settingsYearsOfBeekeeping, settingsSuperNumber);
                    }

                    else {
                        if(e.getCode() == ParseException.OBJECT_NOT_FOUND)
                        {
                            Log.e("Pay Attention", "Got OBJECT NOT FOUND ERROR");
                            PreferencesChange();
                        }

                        else {
                            Log.e("Pay Attention", "Nothing");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });




        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Please Check Parse.com, they stopped their services.

Comment: I am using Back4App.com which does the same thing